# Trying to build an intern Database

Tags: android

I need to build a Database that has 5 columns and I need to add data in a certain activity and read data from another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQLite database for that. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Some tutorials:
http://www.anddev.org/working_with_the_sqlite-database_-_cursors-t319.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954